# How do I set root password for mysql 5.7 on netbsd

Tags: mysql, installation, netbsd

I'm trying to get mySQL 5.7 working on NetBSD (unix). When I try "mysql -u root" I get

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

When I try "mysqld --initialize-insecure" I get

[ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it.

What do I do?

Comment: if you don't have valueable data you could remove the data directory contents and try that again. Otherwise the unix/unix like instructions  [from the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) will work.

Comment: Can you "su - mysql" and then try mysql?

Comment: In the end I deleted mysql and started again. 

I've got somewhere by going su (to become root) and then su mysql, and then "mysqld --initialize". 

That claims to have set a password for root, but it then ignores it: mysql -u root -p 
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I'm still running aground on "mysql -u root -p" --- when I enter the password that mysqld --initialize generates, I still get:  ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES). This happens as me, as root and as mysql users.